# Xregexp javascript optional named group seperated by white spaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, expression, xregexp

I'm looking into an [Xregexp](http://xregexp.com/) expression that support named parameter preceded by letters . Here is my expression :

```
(?:d:|duration:)(?<time>.*\S+).*(?:t:|title:)(?<title>(?:.*\S+))(?:.*(?:(?:p:|prize:)(?<prize>.*\S+)))
```

It is working well, but the problem is I wanna put the `p:<prize>` group as optional, Which expression should I use ?

I'm also trying to end the capture when there is a white space

Example:

**What I want :**

`duration:1h 5m 1s       title:Title test  [p:prize]<-optionnal group`

*I want to have the `prize` group as optional*

**Match with the current expression :**

`duration:1h 5m 1s  title:Title test p:Something random`

Group results:

- `time` : `1h 5m 1s`
- `title` : `Title test`
- `prize` : `Something random`

Comment: Have you tried adding a `?` just before the closing bracket at the end of your regex?

Comment: Group `time` : `1h 5m 1s`
Group `title` : `Title test  p:ee` I already dit it, and the prize group is captured inside the title one

Comment: Just adding `?` won't work. Try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/T3B9o0/2). Or maybe even [like this](https://regex101.com/r/lmOKvH/1).

Comment: Thanks, it's working, and if I wanna add a seconde optional group ?

Comment: What is the second one?

Comment: There [it is](https://regex101.com/r/lmOKvH/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict your patterns a bit to get rid of `.*` that would eat up all up to the last occurrences of subsequent subpatterns. Then, use lazy dot pattern (`.*?`) whenever you need to match a value up to the next key, and add a `$` (end of string) anchor at the end to make sure you will get all the text with the lazy dots.

```
d(?:uration)?:(?<time>.*?)\s*t(?:itle)?:(?<title>.*?)\s*(?:p(?:rize)?:(?<prize>.*))?$
```

See the [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/lmOKvH/1/).

**Details**

- `d(?:uration)?:` - a `d:` or `duration:`
- `(?<time>.*?)` - Group "time": any zero or more chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `t(?:itle)?:` - either `title:` or `t:`
- `(?<title>.*?)`- Group "title": any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:`  - start of an  optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `p(?:rize)?:` - `p:` or `prize:`
  - `(?<prize>.*)` - Group "prize": any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `)?` - end of the optional group
- `$` - end of string.